# How to solve this error of ObjectStateManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem on my code, I have created an Edit.cshtml view in my MVC 5 application.

But before I build the dbo.ObjectStateManager gives my an Error. As below

> Error 1'parishV3.Models.ParishDBSQLEntities' does not contain a
>   definition for 'ObjectStateManager' and no extension method
>   'ObjectStateManager' accepting a first argument of type
>   'parishV3.Models.ParishDBSQLEntities' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and I tried to add namespace : System.data.objects and "objects is not available" and even System.data.entity.core.objects still not working Please help.

Comment: @Ben thanx for responding how do you check this"If your CertsModelContainer is a DbContext, you can cast it to an IObjectContextAdapter in order to access the ObjectStateManager."

Comment: It means does `ParishDBSQLEntities` inherit from `DbContext` .

Comment: ok i get you on that so how do i change it to IObjectContextAdapter   then

Comment: Cast it, something like `((IObjectContextAdapter)myContext).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager`

Comment: ok i ll try to do so

Comment: @ben i tried this but still not working" db.Addresses1.Attach(add);
                    var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
                    db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(add, EntityState.Modified);"

Comment: You don't do that with DbContext to change the state, you do `db.Entry(add).State = EntityState.Modified`

Comment: ok i will that way then, so it means i will not use ObjectStateManager?

Comment: @ben wen i save in one table is working but wen i save in three different tables its not working. it gives me an error that says"An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code" and Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: That is a different problem, SQL server is erroring when it tries to execute the SQL. The inner exception will give you the error, if you still have problems post a new question with all the relevant details.

Comment: `db.Members.Attach(member);
                    db.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;                            
                    db.Contacts.Attach(con);
                    db.Entry(con).State = EntityState.Modified;                    
                    db.Addresses1.Attach(add);
                    db.Entry(add).State = EntityState.Modified;                  
                    db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: ok thank you very much with your time

Comment: @BenRobinson its working that one you said i must do it. not this for ObjectStateManager